# How to change display of candles into Heikin Ashi from script

Tags: pine-script

Changing the way Bar's style into Heikin Ashi from the menu is easy but how can you do it by code?
I would like to avoid that a user has to remember he should change it when he uses an indicator or study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly do that.

You can try calculating the Heikin Ashi values yourself and then use the `plotcandle()` function. This would only work if `overlay=false`.

However, if all you want is a simple warning to the user, I would suggest a simple warning text on the chart. Use `chart.is_heikinashi` built-in variable and print a warning text if the chart is not Heikin Ashi.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)


is_ha = chart.is_heikinashi

var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)

if barstate.islast and not is_ha
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = "Please change to Heikin Ashi")
```

[image]